# Compiling rabbitmq-c to x64 on Win7

Tags: c, 64-bit, rabbitmq-c

I successfully compiled and ran [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) on Win7 as an x86 module (win32).
**Note** that this is a C client for RabbitMQ, and **NOT** RabbitMQ itself.

I used the instructions for `CMAKE` and ran these commands:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build [--config Release] .
```

However I need to compile it to x64. I can't find what switch of configuration option would set the build process to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell CMake that you're targeting 64 bit.

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64" ..
```

... or whichever version of Visual Studio you're using. Then open the generated rabbitmq-c.sln file and build.

There are also some CMake flags listed in the getting started section of the github page that you might find relevant: https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/

Answer (score 0):

Good day, i think you can build in msys2 x64-console, you can download msys2 in next link: [msys2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/). Install needed packages something like this: `pacman -S base-devel git mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`, after that you can simple execute `autoreconf -i ./configure && make install`.

Comment: I was hoping for a vanilla windows compilation, that would just change the settings on my existing compliation

Answer (score 0):

To build rabbitmq-c in 64 bit using Visual Studio 2019 you do like this:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ..
```